# Error while installing Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu, django-rest-framework

I am trying to install django rest framework using official instructions here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation

But this is what I am seeing on my terminal:

```
Collecting djangorestframework
Using cached djangorestframework-3.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: djangorestframework
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/abduaziz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/home/abduaziz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/home/abduaziz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
**kwargs
File "/home/abduaziz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/home/abduaziz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/home/abduaziz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/home/abduaziz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
File "/home/abduaziz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework'
```

I have already tried 10 times or more. Besides, I couldn't clone git repo of djangorestframework. What can I do, guys? Is there any other way to install it?

*My laptop is running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: your `python2.7` installation is probably running with root, so you'll need to `sudo` to install packages

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that, but how to install it using sudo? @MosesKoledoye

Comment: `sudo pip install djangorestframework`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is a permissions issue. You could use `sudo` to install it, but I think the best way would be to use a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) because you won't need to use sudo to install it.

So, either `sudo pip install djangorestframework`

Or use a virtual environment for your project:

```
# set up a new environment (may need to change the path to python)
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
# get inside the virtual environment
source venv/bin/activate
# Install django and django rest framework
pip install django
pip install djangorestframework
```

Comment: sudo pip install djangorestframework
it worked for me! Thanks for ur response!